# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'System Volume Information' when trying to copy files with python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that copies files from the USB stick inserted into the computer to a folder within the hard drive. I keep getting this error: 
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'System Volume Information'`
The code is

```
import os
import shutil
from shutil import copyfile
drives = [ chr(x) + ":" for x in range(65,90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ":") ]
print(drives)


if "E:" in drives:
    with open('backupNumbers.txt', 'r') as f:
        f_contents =f.readlines()
        numberofFolders = int(f_contents[0])
        numberofFolders += 1
    with open('backupNumbers.txt', 'w') as wf:
        wf.write(str(numberofFolders))

    def createFolder(directory):
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)
        except OSError:
            print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +  directory)
    folderNumber = str(numberofFolders)    
    createFolder('./' + "Backup " + folderNumber + '/')
    src = "E:\\"
    dest1 = "Y:\\Documents\\USB Copies\\"
    dest = str(dest1 + "Backup" + folderNumber)
    files = os.listdir(src)
    os.chdir(src)
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(file, f.read())
    for file in files:
        shutil.copy(file, dest)
```

The full traceback is

```
File "<ipython-input-4-fb59bc7c32b6>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/USB Backups/Automation.py', wdir='E:/USB Backups')

  File "C:\Users\Garret Langlois\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Garret Langlois\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "E:/USB Backups/Automation.py", line 30, in <module>
    with open(file) as f:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'System Volume Information'
```

Comment: can you please share the entire traceback

Comment: You're mixing two naming conventions, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: There's probably more code here than is needed to reproduce the problem. Try removing code until you have the smallest program that shows the same failure. For example all the stuff about reading from `backupNumbers.txt` is not essential.

Comment: I was using the `backupNumbers.txt` to create a reference number for the folders to be named off of in which the backups were placed because I couldn't think of a way to have a number that I could add to and reference between runs of the code.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't have it in your code at all, but it's not very relevant to this permission error.

Answer (score 0):

`System Volume Information` is a special folder used by Windows to manage restore points.

You probably don't need to copy it yourself, and I'd suggest you just skip it.

But if you do want to get access to it, you can read about that here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309531/how-to-gain-access-to-the-system-volume-information-folder

Comment: How would I exclude it from being copied?

Comment: Well, it depends what you want the program to do. One good option might be to just catch, print, and continue on any permission-denied errors: see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html